# @NativeCoroutine in KMM fails for iOS build with opt-in requirements

Tags: ios, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I've added a [KMP-NativeCoroutines](https://github.com/rickclephas/KMP-NativeCoroutines) plugin to my KMM project:

`id("com.rickclephas.kmp.nativecoroutines") version "1.0.0-ALPHA-5"`

When I add `@NativeCoroutinesState` or `@NativeCoroutines` annotation to my flow/function iOS build starts to fail with

*This declaration needs opt-in. Its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCName' or '@OptIn(kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCName::class)'*

When I add `@OptIn(kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCName::class)` on top of my flow

```
    @OptIn(kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCName::class)
    @NativeCoroutinesState
    val flow: StateFlow<Long> = MutableStateFlow(5)
```

I receive an error

*This class can only be used as an annotation or as an argument to @OptIn*

Adding opt-in annotation to my class

```
@OptIn(kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCRefinement::class)
class NetworkService {
```

does not change an error, that I receive:

*This class can only be used as an annotation or as an argument to @OptIn*

Any ideas, where should I dig for a fix? Android app works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `OptIn` required in generated code. You can use [Module-wide Opt-in](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/opt-in-requirements.html#module-wide-opt-in) to solve this.

For your Kotlin Multiplatform project you need to add

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    all {
        languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
        languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCName")
    }

    val commonMain by getting { //...
    //...
}
```

Comment: I've tried these code, but with added ```@OptIn(kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCRefinement::class)```. Tried again with only @NativeCoroutines annotation and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewKolubov Not sure where has `kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCRefinement` come from. Original error was about `kotlin.experimental.ExperimentalObjCName`. I thought it quite obvious that Module-wide Opt-in can be used without `@OptIn` annotations. I can add it to answer if you think it make answer more clear.

Answer (score 0):

according to the library documentation [rickclephas](https://github.com/rickclephas/KMM-ViewModel):

Add the library to your shared Kotlin module and opt-in to the ExperimentalForeignApi:

```
kotlin {
   sourceSets {
       all {
           languageSettings.optIn("kotlinx.cinterop.ExperimentalForeignApi")
       }
       commonMain {
           dependencies {
               api("com.rickclephas.kmm:kmm-viewmodel-core:1.0.0-ALPHA-19")
           }
       }
   }
}
```